# Kinect in gazebo for ROS

Tags: gazebo, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey I am new to Gazebo. My project requires  kinect mounted over Pioneer 3DX to track humans in environment as one of its part.. I wanted to know hot to add kinect sensor to my Pioneer 3DX model in Gazebo and receive data in a similar fashion as done by Kinect nodes for ROS. Thanks in advance..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201626/kinect-in-gazebo-for-ros/) by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2015-01-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Googeling for the header of your question brings you to [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) that explain how to add gazebo plugins (kinect among them) to your simulated robot. You can also check [turtlebot_description](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/tree/indigo/turtlebot_description) package for an example of pretty the same of what you want to do.
Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2